# Kivy, dynimic class on KV language

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to use a rule on my KV language to generate classes on the on, but I always get an error.

```
<SimpleInputLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    message_label: message
    user_input: input

    Label:
        id: message
        text: root.message_to_user
    FloatInput: if input_type == 'float' else TextInput:
        id: input
        focus: True
```

What can I do to make this works, if `input_type` is equal `'float'` I want my `input` class to be a `FloatInput`, else a `TextInput`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such thing isn't possible with `kv` lang alone. At least not directly. You have ~4 options:

1. Set `input_type` according to a property of a widget:

   ```
   TextInput:
       hint_text: 'int'
       input_type: 'int' if self.hint_text == 'int' else 'float'
   ```
2. Change `input.input_type` property from outside (if the difference is only input type)
3. Add the right widget dynamically with e.g. `<parent>.add_widget(Factory.FloatInput())` on some event, let's say `on_release` of a `Button`
4. Do it in Python especially in `__init__` when building the layout. It's easier than messing around trying to implement something that's not there or looking for the right event to use for adding a widget in `kv`. It's more flexible.

Although there's probably mentioned in the docs the thing that everything after `:` behaves like a casual Python, but that applies to widget properties & events, not to widgets themselves:

**bad:**

```
v--rule-- :  v------------ not Python -------------v
FloatInput: if input_type == 'float' else TextInput:
```

**good:**

```
TextInput:
    text: 'int'
    # property:  v-------------- Python ---------------v
    input_type: 'int' if self.text == 'int' else 'float'
```